# Problemas con el uso de componentes en Tailwindcss y HTML

Tags: html, tailwind

He estado haciendo un poqueño curso de youtube sobre TailWind, pero al momento de usar las clases y componentes no se aplica la clase que quiero usar parece que todo lo que está en el @layer no lo reconociera. No estoy seguro si debo instalar alguna otra coasa además de lo basico para usar tailwin. No me deja aplicar los valores de color etc. Acá la maqutación de html y el de tailwin:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>TailWind</title>
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Be+Vietnam+Pro:wght@400;500;700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/estilos.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./src/css/output.css">
 
    
</head>
<body class="font-principal">
    <header>
        <nav class="wrapper h-20 flex items-center justify-between">

            <a href="./" class="w-1/3">
            <img src="./images/logo.svg" alt="w-full">
            </a>

            <input type="checkbox" id="menu">
            <label for="menu">Activar/Desactivar</label>
            <div>
                <ul>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">Pricing</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">Product</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">About Us</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">Careers</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">Cominity</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>

            <a href="#"> Get Stared</a>
        </nav>
    </header>
</body>
</html>

    @tailwind base;
    @tailwind components;
    @tailwind utilities;
    @layer components{
    .wrapper{
        @apply w-[90%] mx-auto overflow-hidden max-w-screen-xl bg-red-300;
    }
}
```